# Accessing relative URL's via "ajax" from "file://" content

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, jquery

I'm putting together some demo pages, and one of the things I want to demonstrate involves fetching HTML fragments dynamically with subsequent processing. Thus I've got simple jQuery code like this:

```
$('#target').load('./content_fragment.html', function() {
  $(this).doSomething();
});
```

I'm doing all this from file:// URLs because the whole thing is part of a presentation that I (might) run from a thumb drive or something. Thus, "content_fragment.html" is just another local file, just like the main page that contains that code.

Now this all works just fine from Firefox or Safari, and *other* uses of relative URLs work fine in Chrome (iframe "src" URLs, images, scripts, css, etc), but Chrome just won't pay attention to those ".load()" requests at all.  If I zip up the content and deploy it to a web server, and then get at it via its "http:" URL, then Chrome works fine. When it doesn't work, I don't see any errors in the Chrome console; it just doesn't fetch the content. I've tried it with Chrome on Linux and XP, with identical results. (And Safari or Firefox to the same file:// URLs always do what I expect and load the content.)

So my question is, is this weirdness just a Chrome quirk, or is there something inherently questionable about XMLHttpRequests and file:// URLs?  In other words, is Chrome doing the *right* thing, meaning the other browsers are broken?

Comment: Its for security, you don't want evil code going into your HD.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add `--allow-file-access-from-files` to the command line when launching chrome to disable this security feature :)

Is it a bug?  Maybe, maybe not, what's happening is it's not treating `file://` as a single domain, requests to a different file are treated as a different domain and therefore blocked by the [SOP rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  It's a choice by the Chrome/Chromium developers, whether it's the correct one depends on your point of view I suppose.

There's a lot of dicusssion on this in the Chrome issues section on Google code, you may find the discussion of interest, [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47416).

Comment: You're an amazing fount of knowledge.  Thanks! I did do some googling but I could find nothing relevant.  I agree that whether this is "right" or "wrong" is a matter of opinion,and as long as I can control the behavior I don't care :-)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue in Safari+Firefox:

The alert in code below does not run:

$.getScript('script.js', function () { alert("Script loaded and executed."); })

Loading an external file instead of script.js will run.