# Jquery getScript($.getScript()) not working on chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, getscript

I have a problem using `$.getScript()` on chrome. It doesn't work on chrome browser. I've tested it on firefox, ie and safari and it worked. All I have on my external script is an `alert()` and it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

**page**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnGet").click(function(){
   $.getScript("script.js");
  });
});
```

**script.js**

```
alert('Get script loading');
```

Is anyone have experienced this problem?

Comment: on my html is this

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#btnGet").click(function(){
  $.getScript("script.js");     
});
});

on script.js is only this
alert('Get script loading');

Comment: Code would help. It would also help if you could describe where your page and your script are. If they're local, then you're running into a problem I just stumbled on over the weekend, which Nick Craver was good enough to help with:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430638/accessing-relative-urls-via-ajax-from-file-content

Comment: Yes, it is local. So, is there any work around? I can't believe the chromium team is doing that.

Comment: yes, the workaround is in the post @pointy links to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for making it clear to me.

I think I would have my script inline instead since the inline code will work fine on all browsers.