# jQuery XML Parse (with Ajax) Does Not Work in Chrome (but works in IE, FF, Opera, Safari)

Tags: jquery, xml, google-chrome

I am using jQuery.ajax to parse some xml from a file. Everything works fine in IE (6,7,8), Firefox, Opera and Safari, but fails with Google Chrome. Here is the code:

```
/* ... */
this.loadXml = function()
{
 $.ajax(
 {
  type: "GET",
  url: "some_file.xml",
  dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
  success: function(xml)
  {
   if($.browser.msie)
   {
    var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
    xml = xmlDoc;
   }

  /* parsing starts here */
  /* for example: in the document I have a div tag with id "some text" and the xml file contains: <root><tag>test</tag></root>*/

  $("#some_id").text($(xml).find("root > tag").text());

  /* parsing ends here */

  }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome is not going to let you access a local file like that.  It's a (somewhat contentious) security thing. You can start chrome from the command line with a flag to force it to allow access however:

```
google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

(My thanks for this again to @Nick Craver, man of infinite knowledge.)

*edit* — here's the question I asked: [Accessing relative URL's via "ajax" from "file://" content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430638/accessing-relative-urls-via-ajax-from-file-content)

Comment: Yeah... that seems to be the problem... Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score -1):

just replace the short url with the full url...

from

url: "some_file.xml",

to

url: "http://www.domain.com/some_file.xml",

Comment: how does that work when loading a LOCAL .xml file?  (which is where the problem stems from)