# Cannot load XML in Chrome with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax

Why does the following code work in firefox and not chrome? I'm testing this locally.

Thanks.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('#test').load('todo.xml');
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome does not allow access to local files by default. You can get around this feature by starting Chrome from the command line:

> chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files

Check out [Nick Craver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430638/accessing-relative-urls-via-ajax-from-file-content/3430644#3430644) for more details.